# Cast to multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting an object to two interfaces at the same time, to call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898925/casting-an-object-to-two-interfaces-at-the-same-time-to-call-a-generic-method)

I'm fairly sure you can't do this so I'm wondering if there's a workaround, but I need/want to cast an object to represent multiple interfaces for use with generic constraints. For example:

```
public void Foo<T>(T t) where T : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB
{
}
```

If I have an object I want to say something like `var t = (IInterfaceA | IInterfaceB)someObj;` so I can pass `t` into this method.

Is there a nifty way of doing this? I'm using C# 3.5 so no dynamic available, but if it's possible with dynamic please post it anyway.

Comment: What type do you want t to be after the cast?

Comment: Check covariance concept of .net framework 4, it may help but for that also you need to change the implementation.

Comment: Cant we have inheritance of interfaces?

Comment: @CJBrew well I guess it'll be a type that doesn't exist, but realises both interface. Akin to an anonymous type.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, that's the other solution I was thinking, but for various reasons I didn't want to go down that route (although I'll probably have to!)

Comment: @user751975  I've used co-contra variance in other projects that are using C# 4.0 and I don't believe that would solve this issue - but thanks for the idea

Comment: Can you elaborate on the scenario you need this in? I can't think of a single case, you would need it...

Comment: @Daniel I want to call Foo if my object realises both interfaces, and Bar if it realises different interfaces. The type I have is not specific enough (let's say it's type `object`) so I need to cast to both interfaces so I can pass my object into the method.

Comment: Definite duplicate! I didn't see that in the list of similar questions as I was typing the question. Good find, thanks

Comment: You cannot have an item which is a fish and chair simultaneously.

Comment: @lukas I don't see how that comment to adds to the discussion

Comment: @lukas: What do you want to say with your comment?

Comment: @RichK: Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: if there is no relation between these two interfaces IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB you cannot do what you want. What do you care about is the behaviour of those two object expressed by interfaces. You have problem with interfaces or your method is too coupuled (can't say which with this tiny abstract snippet). Similar, you have two pets, let's say a fish and a dog and you want to feed one of them, you can look at theirs behaviour - both can eat - or the fact that they are mammals and a mammal can eat.

Comment: @lukas there is a relation. Let's take your example, I have two interfaces, IBreathable and IMoveable. Both Dog and Fish realise these two interfaces and both breath and move in very different ways. I have  a method that requires something which is both - let's say it need to call Breathe whenever we Move so we don't get out of breath and die. I need to cast to both types, but not specifically Fish and not specifically Dog as I have many animals in my farm.

Comment: @RichK "say it need to call Breathe whenever we Move" it is one behaviour, define a new inteface (with inheritance) that describes desired behaviour. It will keep thing more explicite and IMO simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

Despite the answer below, I would say the better solution is the one that most other answers point to.  (This assumes that you can redefine the multiple classes that implement both interfaces.)

Create an interface that inherits from both InterfaceA and InterfaceB, then, for all classes that implement interfaces A and B, replace those interfaces with the new one.  Before:

```
class SomeClass : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { }
class AnotherClass : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { }
class AdditionalClass : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { }
```

After:

```
interface IInterfaceC : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { }
class SomeClass : IInterfaceC { }
class AnotherClass : IInterfaceC { }
class AdditionalClass : IInterfaceC { }
```

The implementation of Foo is then fairly trivial.  And, again, since you don't know at compile time what type you have on hand, you may be able just to declare it as

```
public void Foo(IInterfaceC someObj) { }
```

END EDIT

---

You can do it using reflection, though some will say that this isn't particularly "nifty":

```
public class FooClass
{
    public void Foo<T> (T t) where T : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB
    {
        //... do your thing here
    }
    private static void Example(object someObj)
    {
        var type = someObj.GetType();
        if(typeof(IInterfaceA).IsAssignableFrom(type) && typeof(IInterfaceB).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            var genericMethod = typeof(FooClass).GetMethod("Foo");
            var constructedMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            var instance = new FooClass();
            var result = constructedMethod.Invoke(instance, new [] { someObj });
            Assert.IsNull(result);
        }
    }
}
```

you could also do this, which could allow you to make Foo non-generic.  It's also fairly ugly, so I would hide this ugliness by making it private:

```
private void PrivateFoo(IInterfaceA objA, IInterfaceB objB)
{
    if (!ReferenceEquals(objA, objB))
        throw new ArgumentException("objA and objB must refer to the same object");

    //... do your thing here
}
public void Foo(object someObj)
{
    PrivateFoo((IInterfaceA)someObj, (IInterfaceB)someObj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Foo<T>(T t) where T : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB{}
{
  // T already implements IInterfaceA and IInterfaceB, just call the methods.
  t.MethodFromA();
  t.MethodFromB();
}
```

---

```
T t = (T)someObj;
```

This will cast the object to T, not the two interfaces... so it's up to you to make sure that'll work.

---

```
IInterfaceA tA = (IInterfaceA)someObj;
IInterfaceB tB = (IInterfaceB)someObj;
```

Two references to the one instance.

Comment: Sorry I think my question was badly worded, I don't want to do the cast in the method, I want to do the outside so I can pass it into the method

Comment: You don't have to cast to call.  Just use any Type that implements both.

Comment: Yea the thing is at the point when I call Foo, I don't know at compile time what the type is, I can't cast it to a defined type because there are multiple classes that realise both interfaces

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way.
The only thing that comes close is to create another interface the inherits those two interfaces. But then all your classes need to implement that third interface instead of the two others, so in most circumstances, this is not practical.

Just cast it to that interface you need at that moment.

**UPDATE:**
The only way I can see is to create a container class that implements those interfaces:

```
class Container : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB
{
    private object _obj;

    public Container(object obj)
    {
        // Check that the object really implements those two interfaces.

        _obj = obj;
    }

    void IInterfaceA.Method1()
    {
        ((IInterfaceA)_obj).Method1();
    }

    // And so on for all methods of the interfaces.
}
```

Comment: The container class won't work if you have an instance of a class that implements both interfaces but does not inherit from the container class.  In other words, for example, System.String implements both IComparable<string> and IEnumerable<char>.  If you create `class X : IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>`, you will not be able to assign strings to variables of this type, nor vice versa.

Comment: @phoog: I don't follow. You don't want to assign the `string` to `X` but pass it into the constructor...

Comment: Aha, I see.  Sorry, I was reading too quickly and I didn't understand the approach you were suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is have inheritance of interfaces. Move the common functionality, to the parent interface, which should be used in above scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to restructure your inheritance to achieve your goal.

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Note that ArrayList inerits from IList, which inherits from two interfaces already included in Arraylist.