# Extend generic type to inherited interface

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface, casting, deserialization

I hope I do not repeat a question that is already solved but I had troubles to find a solution for my problem in similar questions.
I found this topic in the forum: [Casting an object to two interfaces at the same time, to call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898925/casting-an-object-to-two-interfaces-at-the-same-time-to-call-a-generic-method). Honestly my C# is very bad since I am coding only in VB.NET and I think my issue is a bit different (inherited interfaces instead of stand alone).

My problem is as well related to serialization (XML) for which my implementation of generics fails throwing an exception. The point is that I have to cast my generic type, the serializer shall deserialize into, to an interface, which results in an exception.
To better explain please see the simplified example code below:

```
    Public Interface IParent
       Property ParentProp As String
    End Interface

    Public Interface IChild
       Inherits IParent
       Property ChildProp As String
    End Interface

    Public Class ExampleClass
       Implements IChild

       Public Property ChildProp As String = "Child Property" Implements IChild.ChildProp
       Public Property ParentProp As String = "Parent Property" Implements IParent.ParentProp
    End Class

    Public Class ExampleListClass
       Inherits List(Of Integer)
       Implements IChild

       Public Property ChildProp As String = "List Child Property" Implements IChild.ChildProp
       Public Property ParentProp As String = "List Parent Property" Implements IParent.ParentProp
    End Class

    Public Class TestEnv
       Public Shared Sub Main()
          Dim str As String

          Dim locExampleListClass = New ExampleListClass
          str = TestEnv.Method1(Of Integer, ExampleListClass)(locExampleListClass)
          MessageBox.Show(str, "locExampleListClass", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

          Dim locExampleClass = New ExampleClass
          str = TestEnv.Method2(locExampleClass)
          str = TestEnv.Method2_Dirty(locExampleClass)
          MessageBox.Show(str, "locExampleClass", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
       End Sub

       Public Shared Function Method1(Of T, C As {IList(Of T), IParent})(ByRef Instance As C) As String
          If TypeOf (Instance) Is IChild Then
             'Since instance is of type C which is restricted to IParent, the passed instance is a list which implements IChild (and of course IParent - because IChild inherits IParent)
             Dim CastedInstance = DirectCast(Instance, IChild)
             '!-----------------PseudoCode-----------------!
             'Dim CastedInstance = DirectCast(Instance, {C, IChild})
             Dim ReturnVal = TestEnv.Method2(CastedInstance)
             Dim fake = TestEnv.Method2_Dirty(Instance)

             Return ReturnVal
          Else
             'Something else is done (e.g. deactivating context menues only useful for IChild)
             Return Instance.ParentProp
          End If
          '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       End Function

       Public Shared Function Method2(Of T As {IChild})(ByRef Instance As T) As String
          Return Instance.ChildProp

          'Note: Xml-serialization into T when T is an interface seems not possible. Thus type C in Method1 needs to be maintained but extended to IChild
       End Function

       Public Shared Function Method2_Dirty(Of T As {IParent})(ByRef Instance As T) As String
          'This would work but is not very nice (there is a reason why T shall be restricted to IChild in the first place - no ifs or trycasts needed)
          If TypeOf (Instance) Is IChild Then
             Return DirectCast(Instance, IChild).ChildProp
          Else
             Throw New Exception("The input parameter needs to be of type IChild but I am too stupid to make it work")
          End If
       End Function
    End Class
```

So there are two example classes one being a list and being very simple. Both implement the interface IChild. Method1 however restricts the inputargument only to IParent and checks if IChild is implemented. If not something else is done. If yes the instance can be casted without trouble. Thus at this point I know that the instance implements IList(of T) and IChild.
Now Method2 can be called with the casted instance. All this obviously compiles and works. My problem is that Method2 in my case is a deserializer (trying to indicate this by passing Instance ByRef). Since the CastedInstance is of type IChild the deserializer throws an exception.

Thus I would need still the type C but extended by IChild. After the if statement in Method1, I know that the instance fullfills the restrictions, but I fail to implement the correct code (see commented PseudeCode).
I guess I could implement the Method2_Dirty which only restricts to IParent and do type checks and trycasts. Nonetheless this seems not very nice since then exceptions are thrown at runtime and not during coding before compiling.

As said in the beginning I hope I do not repeat any questions and looking forward for your feedback. Thanks

Comment: TL;DR; isn't DataContractSerializer up to the job for this?

Comment: I'm concerned that the devil may be in the details that you omitted.  There's nothing that jumps out at me as being obviously wrong, although I would note that constraints don't necessarily take "obvious" type relationships into account the way you might think that they would---also see Eric Lippert's blog entry from some years back here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints/

Comment: The other thing is, even though you have coded type checks that can satisfy you as to the type, the compiler isn't necessarily smart enough to figure this out.  In that case, you are likely to need a runtime type check, but if you set it up properly, it should be effectively guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. The blog provided by Craig made me smile (quite neerdy though to smile about generics :-)). I agree with Craig that something feels wrong but at the same time it feels that such an extension feature would be nice. But then we are back to the blog...

Hope I find the time in the comming days to think about it more and look to the DataContractSerializer suggested by Aybe. I am thinking as well to overload my Method2 to get two versions: One with runtime checks and one for compiler checks...

Answer (score 0):

after some time of investigation I found a solution that is satisfactory for me. I would like to share it with the community. Maybe it is helpful for someone in the future. In case somebody has a better solution please let me know...

I realized that my problem is acutally related to XML serialization (with binary serialization no exception occurs). Thanks Aybe for pushing me in this direction. I guess that the problem could be solved with the DataContractSerializer class. However I implemented something else that is closer to the generic topic of this post.

Below is an extension of the initial example, which works out the issue more clearly (I hope). It includs de/serialization now to show what the actual problem is. Sorry it got quite long

```
    Public Interface IParent
       Property ParentProp As String
    End Interface

    Public Interface IImportable
       Inherits IParent
       Property ChildProp As String
    End Interface

    <Serializable> Public Class ExampleClass
       Implements IImportable

       Public Property ChildProp As String = "Child Property" Implements IImportable.ChildProp
       Public Property ParentProp As String = "Parent Property" Implements IParent.ParentProp
    End Class

    <Serializable> Public Class ExampleClass_NonImportableList
       Inherits List(Of Integer)
       Implements IParent

       Public Property ParentProp As String = "Parent Property" Implements IParent.ParentProp
    End Class

    <Serializable> Public Class ExampleClass_List
       Inherits List(Of Integer)
       Implements IImportable

       Public Property ChildProp As String = "List Child Property" Implements IImportable.ChildProp
       Public Property ParentProp As String = "List Parent Property" Implements IParent.ParentProp
    End Class

    Public Class TestEnv
       Private Enum En_DeSerializationMode
          Xml
          Binary
       End Enum

       Public Shared Sub Main()
          'Define some instances
          Dim locExampleClass = New ExampleClass
          Dim locExampleClass_NonImportableList = New ExampleClass_NonImportableList From {1, 3, 5, 7}
          Dim locExampleClass_List = New ExampleClass_List From {11, 13, 15, 17}

          'Set mode and filenames
          'Dim SeriMode = En_DeSerializationMode.Binary
          Dim SeriMode = En_DeSerializationMode.Xml
          Dim FileExt = If(SeriMode = En_DeSerializationMode.Binary, ".bin", ".xml")
          Dim File1 = New IO.FileInfo("ExampleClass" & FileExt)
          Dim File2 = New IO.FileInfo("ExampleClass_NonImportableList" & FileExt)
          Dim File3 = New IO.FileInfo("ExampleClass_List" & FileExt)

          'Export the instances
          TestEnv.ExportToFile(File1, SeriMode, locExampleClass)
          TestEnv.ExportToFile(File2, SeriMode, locExampleClass_NonImportableList)
          TestEnv.ExportToFile(File3, SeriMode, locExampleClass_List)

          'Import form the files and add to lists
          'Obviously complier error: TestEnv.CheckImportFromFile(Of Integer, ExampleClass)(New IO.FileInfo(File1 & FileExt), SeriMode, locExampleClass) 
          TestEnv.ImportFromFile(File1, SeriMode, locExampleClass) 'Direct import can be done
          TestEnv.CheckImportFromFile(Of Integer, ExampleClass_NonImportableList)(File2, SeriMode, locExampleClass_NonImportableList)
          TestEnv.CheckImportFromFile(Of Integer, ExampleClass_List)(File3, SeriMode, locExampleClass_List)
       End Sub

       Private Shared Sub ExportToFile(Of C)(ExportFile As IO.FileInfo, Mode As En_DeSerializationMode, InstanceTarget As C)
          'Set the serialization routine according to the mode
          Dim LambdaSerializer As Action
          Select Case Mode
             Case En_DeSerializationMode.Binary
                LambdaSerializer = Sub()
                                      Dim locFs = New IO.FileStream(ExportFile.FullName, IO.FileMode.Create)
                                      Using locFs
                                         Dim locBinaryFormatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(Nothing,
                                                                                                                                     New System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.File))
                                         locBinaryFormatter.Serialize(locFs, InstanceTarget)
                                         locFs.Flush()
                                         locFs.Close()
                                      End Using
                                   End Sub
             Case Else 'En_DeSerializationMode.Xml
                LambdaSerializer = Sub()
                                      Dim locXmlWriter = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(InstanceTarget.GetType)
                                      Dim locXmlFile = New IO.StreamWriter(ExportFile.FullName)
                                      Using locXmlFile
                                         locXmlWriter.Serialize(locXmlFile, InstanceTarget)
                                         locXmlFile.Flush()
                                         locXmlFile.Close()
                                      End Using
                                   End Sub
          End Select

          'Serialize the instance to the file
          Try
             LambdaSerializer.Invoke()
          Catch ex As Exception
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Export error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
          End Try
       End Sub

       Private Shared Sub CheckImportFromFile(Of T, C As {IList(Of T), IParent})(ImportFile As IO.FileInfo, Mode As En_DeSerializationMode, ByRef InstanceTarget As C)
          'One dirty solution would be of course to implement IImportable to each class passed to CheckImportFromFile: But this would make no sense, craete effort and would just satisfy the compiler
          If TypeOf (InstanceTarget) Is IImportable Then
             Dim Imported As IImportable = Nothing
             'Dim Imported As C               'This creates a compiler error because C does not implement IImportable
             'Dim Imported As {C,IImportable} 'PseudoCode!!!
             TestEnv.ImportFromFile(ImportFile, Mode, Imported) ' This causes an exception when using Xml deserialization (binary works)
             If Imported IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ImportedList As C
                Try
                   'Try block to prevent that an instance is imported that by incident fulfills the C restrictions but is not of InstanceTarget type
                   ImportedList = DirectCast(Imported, C)
                Catch ex As Exception
                   MessageBox.Show("The imported instance of type " & Imported.GetType.ToString & " could not be converted to the target type " & GetType(C).ToString, "Import error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                   Exit Sub
                End Try
                'Add the imported items to the target instance list
                For Each locItem In ImportedList
                   InstanceTarget.Add(locItem)
                Next
             End If

             'Without restriction but with runtime checks
             Dim Imported2 As C
             TestEnv.ImportFromFile_RuntimeChecks(ImportFile, Mode, Imported2)
             If Imported2 IsNot Nothing Then
                'Now no trycast to C (respectively IList) is needed 
                For Each locItem In Imported2
                   InstanceTarget.Add(locItem)
                Next
             End If

             'Final solution
             Dim Imported3 As C
             TestEnv.ImportFromFile_Final(ImportFile, Mode, Imported3, Function(locImported)
                                                                          'This makes programmer aware that the imported instance has to be importable (try block in ImportFromFile method)
                                                                          Return DirectCast(locImported, IImportable)
                                                                       End Function)
             If Imported3 IsNot Nothing Then
                'Now no trycast to C (respectively IList) is needed
                For Each locItem In Imported3
                   InstanceTarget.Add(locItem)
                Next
             End If
          Else
             'Something else is done (e.g. deactivating context menues)
             MessageBox.Show("Instance of type " & GetType(C).ToString & " will not be imported", "No import", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
          End If
       End Sub

       Private Shared Sub ImportFromFile(Of C As {IImportable})(ImportFile As IO.FileInfo, SerializationMode As En_DeSerializationMode, ByRef ImportedInstance As C)
          ImportedInstance = TestEnv.FileDeserializer(Of C)(ImportFile, SerializationMode)
          If ImportedInstance Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

          'Do something after import
          ImportedInstance.ChildProp += " (I was imported)"
       End Sub

       Private Shared Sub ImportFromFile_RuntimeChecks(Of C As {IParent})(ImportFile As IO.FileInfo, SerializationMode As En_DeSerializationMode, ByRef ImportedInstance As C)
          ImportedInstance = TestEnv.FileDeserializer(Of C)(ImportFile, SerializationMode)
          If ImportedInstance Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

          'This would work but is not very nice (there is a reason why C shall be restricted to IImportable in the first place - no ifs or trycasts needed)
          If TypeOf (ImportedInstance) Is IImportable Then
             'Do something after import
             DirectCast(ImportedInstance, IImportable).ChildProp += " (I was imported with RuntimeChecks)"
          Else
             Throw New Exception("The input parameter needs to be of type IImportable but I (or the compiler :-)) am too stupid to make it work")
          End If
       End Sub

       Private Shared Sub ImportFromFile_Final(Of C As {IParent})(ImportFile As IO.FileInfo, SerializationMode As En_DeSerializationMode, ByRef ImportedInstance As C, ImportedCaster As Func(Of C, IImportable))
          ImportedInstance = TestEnv.FileDeserializer(Of C)(ImportFile, SerializationMode)
          If ImportedInstance Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

          Dim ImportedInstanceCast As IImportable
          Try
             ImportedInstanceCast = ImportedCaster.Invoke(ImportedInstance)
          Catch ex As Exception
             MessageBox.Show("Instance of type " & ImportedInstance.GetType.ToString & " cannot be converted to IImportable", "No import", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
             Exit Sub
          End Try

          'Do something after import
          ImportedInstanceCast.ChildProp += " (I was imported smart)"
       End Sub

       Private Shared Function FileDeserializer(Of C)(ImportFile As IO.FileInfo, SerializationMode As En_DeSerializationMode) As C
          'Check that the file exists
          If Not ImportFile.Exists Then
             MessageBox.Show("File does not exist", "File error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
             Return Nothing
          End If

          'Define reader
          Dim LambdaDeserializer As Func(Of Object)
          Select Case SerializationMode
             Case En_DeSerializationMode.Binary
                LambdaDeserializer = Function()
                                        Dim locFs = New IO.FileStream(ImportFile.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)
                                        Dim locObject As Object
                                        Using locFs
                                           Dim locBinaryFormatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(Nothing,
                                                                                                                                       New System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.File))
                                           locObject = locBinaryFormatter.Deserialize(locFs)
                                           locFs.Close()
                                        End Using

                                        Return locObject
                                     End Function
             Case Else 'En_DeSerializationMode.Xml
                LambdaDeserializer = Function()
                                        Dim locXmlReader = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(C))
                                        Dim locXmlFile = New IO.StreamReader(ImportFile.FullName)
                                        Dim locObject As Object
                                        Using locXmlFile
                                           locObject = locXmlReader.Deserialize(locXmlFile)
                                           locXmlFile.Close()
                                        End Using
                                        Return locObject
                                     End Function
          End Select

          'Deserialize the file
          Dim ImportedInstance As C
          Try
             Dim DeseriObj = LambdaDeserializer.Invoke
             ImportedInstance = DirectCast(DeseriObj, C)
          Catch ex As Exception
             MessageBox.Show("Error during deserialization: " & ex.Message, "Import error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
          End Try
          Return ImportedInstance
       End Function
    End Class
```

To describe a bit the example:

- Some instances are created and serialized to files
- Afterwards they shall be deserialized/imported again
- The point is that after the import something shall be done with the imported instance (in this example only the ChildProperty string is changed)
- At a last step the imported list items are added to the initial list. Thus the types have to match which is accomplished by generics (not too important for the issue but to be complete what I want to do)
- The first version ImportFromFile creates problems for Xml serialization, which is why I craeted this post (would be nice if we could extend the generic type C somehow since we know that it would work - see the TypeOf check in CheckImportFromFile)
- The second version ImportFromFile_RuntimeChecks uses runtime checks which would be possible but are obviously not too nice for the programmer (no sign what is needed by the method during coding)
- The final version ImportFromFile_Final requires an additional input parameter function, which pares the importedinstance to the required type to change the Child-property. I consider this solution as sufficient because this way the programmer (most propably myself) is aware that this cast has to work, thus the interface shall be implemented in the class.

I consider this as sufficient in terms of code communication. As said if someone has a better idea please post...